# Matrix and Lattice Paths

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, matrices, graph-theory, integer-lattices

I have a $k\times k$ matrix
$$
A_{k}=
  \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 &1 & 0\\
 &\vdots & &\vdots \\
1 & 1 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0
  \end{pmatrix}
$$
where $k\ge 1$. I wish that the $(1,1)$-entry of $(A_{k})^{n}$ is counting the something related to the weighted lattice paths which lies between $y=0$ and $y=k$, starting from $(0,0)$ and ends at $(0,l)$, for some $l\ge 0$.

The steps allowed are the following:

1. One unit horizontally to the right
2. One unit diagonally to the upper-right
3. One unit diagonally to the down-right
4. It cannot go below $y=0$ or above $y=k$

If needed, we can associate a weight on each step

1. For each diagonal step, associate it with weight $1$
2. For each step horizontally to the right at top level (i.e. $y=k$), associate it with weight $0$
3. For each step horizontally to the right at non-top level (i.e. $y\not= k$), I am not sure which weight I should associate it with (maybe still $1$?)

**Question: can we realize the $(1,1)$-entry of the matrix $A_{k}^{n}$ as counting (weighted) lattice path? **

I know that the matrix can count the paths in a directed graph, but the relationship between matrix and lattice graph is not very clear to me. Intuitively I felt that "directed graph" is very close to "lattice path", but I cannot make it rigorous. I would appreciate it if someone can give me some ideas or reference, especially on how to use matrix in counting lattice paths.

Comment: If you want to start from lattice paths and come to a matrix, describe exactly which steps are allowed in your paths: diagonal? Non-diagonal? Can we go left (i.e. backwards)? Etc.

Or you want to start from this matrix and figure out which paths does it count?

Comment: @colt_browning Thank you very much! I just edited the question and include the information you suggested.